# second condition not being met when condition is called

Tags: php

The below is the basics of my activation code, the user is sent a link when registering to activate. when they click the link it activates and functions as it should, if the token in the link does not match any in the database it should redirect with error message, this is the hangup it don't redirect or even show the error message it just stays on a blank page.

I am really not sure what I missed I even tried a else if what am i missing

```
   if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") && isset($_GET['hash_token'])) {

        $db = DB_CONNECT();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, email, confirm_code FROM users WHERE confirm_code = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['hash_token']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $email = $row['email'];
            $confirm_code = $row['confirm_code'];

            if ($confirm_code !== null && $confirm_code === $_GET['hash_token']) {

                $is_activated = 1;
                $set_confirm_code = null;

                $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET is_activated = ?, confirm_code = ?  WHERE confirm_code = ?");
                $stmt2->bind_param('sss', $is_activated, $set_confirm_code, $confirm_code);
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->close();

                set_message("Your account has been activated please login.", SUCCESS);
                redirect_to_url("/");


            } else {
            

                set_message("Unable to activate with provided data.", WARNING);
                redirect_to_url("/");


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have possibly outputted something before redirecting. This could be an error message or even whitespace. {Turn on errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)  and you'll certainly find sth.

Comment: `$stmt->close();` before the `fetch` I think would be an issue. Not too familiar with mysqli though

Comment: How is `confirm_code` set? You don't need `if ($confirm_code !== null && $confirm_code === $_GET['hash_token']) {` if you enter the `while` you know it matches. I'd guess you can get confirm_code collisions with the current logic. Should check `email` as well.

Comment: @user3783243 Ive tried several different things the only thing is not functioning is if they already activated or they but in a random key at the end of url it dont redirect

Comment: There's nothing to fetch if there isn't a match so the `while` won't be entered.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks for the help i was trying to change the function to a newer style but still in my learning stages

Comment: @Devflow You still have some other issues here. Unclear how `confirm_code` is generating but if you have 2 users with the same value they both would get activated with this code. Also a user could bruteforce all users with this. You should check for the pairing of email and unique key.

Comment: @user3783243 the confirm code is generated when the user registers `$confirm_code = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
    $hashed_confirm_code = hash_hmac('sha256', $confirm_code,'HASH_SECRET_KEY',);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229125/discussion-between-devflow-and-user3783243).

Comment: Random != unique. You either need to make a unique constraint on DB column, and regenerate when conflict, or check that email and hash match.

Comment: already assigned the equal email also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `$stmt` return `null` results while block won't be executed.
Try this

```php
<?php

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") && isset($_GET['hash_token'])) {

    $db = DB_CONNECT();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, email, confirm_code FROM users WHERE confirm_code = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['hash_token']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    
            $email = $row['email'];
            $confirm_code = $row['confirm_code'];
    
            if ($confirm_code !== null && $confirm_code === $_GET['hash_token']) {
    
                $is_activated = 1;
                $set_confirm_code = null;
    
                $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET is_activated = ?, confirm_code = ?  WHERE confirm_code = ?");
                $stmt2->bind_param('sss', $is_activated, $set_confirm_code, $confirm_code);
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->close();
    
                set_message("Your account has been activated please login.", SUCCESS);
                redirect_to_url("/");
    
    
            } else {
            
    
                set_message("Unable to activate with provided data.", WARNING);
                redirect_to_url("/");
    
    
            }
        }
    } else {
        set_message("Unable to activate with provided data.", WARNING);
        redirect_to_url("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_row removed in php 7

Comment: Updated with `mysqli_fetch_row`

Comment: Won't `mysqli_fetch_row` advance the cursor? The num rows function should be used.

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you. .

Comment: @Devflow please update you code